# Android Custom View with time-based updates

Tags: android

I'm aware there's a digital clock widget that's available, but for learning purposes I decided to create a custom widget by extending the View class. I'm successfully drawing the time unto the screen, but I don't know the proper way of getting the view to update the time every second.

I need something that will tell the view to redraw itself every second to update the time. What's the right way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a timer? If you are then you can do this:

```
    private Timer timer;
    private int seconds;

    ...

    seconds = 0;
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new UpdateViewTask(), 0, 1000);
    //1000 is in milliseconds so this is one second

    ...

    private class UpdateViewTask extends TimerTask{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    seconds++;
                    //update view here
                    view.setText(secondsToHHMMSS(seconds));
                }
            });
        }
    }

public static String secondsToHHMMSS(int secs) {

    int hours = secs / 3600;
    int remainder = secs % 3600;
    int minutes = remainder / 60;
    int seconds = remainder % 60;

    return ( (hours < 10 ? "0" : "") + hours
            + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutes
            + ":" + (seconds< 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds );

}
```

Comment: I get it, I should periodically set the time outside of the View and invalidate it to request a redraw. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably invalidateSelf() on the drawable with your timer...you can check the [developer docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#invalidateSelf%28%29) for the details. Note the "Does nothing if there is no Callback attached to the Drawable" statement, or nothing will happen!